# Button does not shown in jquery-mobile table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I dynamically append the rows into the table with a button, but the button show only a text with an underline.
Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/leaderdevil/m73fc/4/)

```
<table data-role="table" id="AssuredDamagedPos" data-mode="reflow"
                    class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-priority="persist">Position</th>
            <th data-priority="persist">Level</th>
            <th data-priority="persist"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> [Position] </td>
            <td> [Level] </td>
            <td><a href="#" data-role="button">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Could anyone help me to figure out how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

move your **jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min** includes AFTER the **jquery-1.10.2.min.js**